# Invalid JWT signature after upgrading jhipster

Tags: jwt, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I builded two microservices applications with jhipster (4.14.5), today i updated the both to 5.1.0. With jhister-registry last docker image (4.0.0)

All work as expected but the API Calls with jwt signature doesnt work anymore.

**MyRequestInterceptor**

```
@Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
        String secret= Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject("admin")
            .claim("auth", AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, properties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getJwt().getSecret())
            .compact();
        requestTemplate.header(JWTConfigurer.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "Bearer " + secret);
    }
```

What is new in jhipster 5.1.0 with JWT? should i change the algorithm signature or how to fix this?

Comment: Which app is showing the error?  I'm pretty sure nothing changed in regards to JWT

Comment: The called APP send the error, iti is the one exposing his API. The calling APP send the same bearer like into the old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we changed the way the secret key is handled, have a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/v5.1.0/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/security/jwt/TokenProvider.java.ejs#L62).

The difference is that now the JWT secret key is encoded in Base64 (that's why we create the encoder [here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/v5.1.0/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/security/jwt/TokenProvider.java.ejs#L46)).

This is originally my fault: the `.signWith()` method from JJWT accepts a String, so I was just giving the secret key (which is a String). But if you look at the documentation of the method, you'll notice that this String should be encoded in Base64. So now you have to use the encoded version of the secret key everywhere. It doesn't change anything in the end, in fact, but it's just to use the API correctly.

Comment: I just generated a project from scratch using jhipster-registry, uaa and gateway micro-service app and I am pretty sure I am having an error related to this new configuration. I haven't notice any update in the Jhipter-Registry documentation tough, maybe now we have to pass some parameters using the encrypted string?? or is this a problem that have to be reported as a bug? since it is happening also with new projects